# Angular2-Cookie Prevents build in AzureDevOps

Tags: angular, cookies, azure-devops, angular2-cookie

I'm making an an angular app that uses cookies. I'm testing it locally, using angular2-cookie/core and everything seems to be working fine.

But when I try to publish it on AzureDevOps it breaks, with this error message:

ERROR in app/app.module.ts(50,39): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Could not resolve angular2-cookie/core relative to /home/vsts/work/1/s/PictureLink.UI/ClientApp/src/app/app.module.ts..
src/app/app.module.ts(16,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-cookie/core'. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/PictureLink.UI/PictureLink.UI.csproj]

I am losing my damn mind. Why does it work fine here and not there? What can I even try to change?

Comment: I guess you did not install the package properly. You probably installed it with -dev.
Deletes this package when you get the build from the project.
Please reinstall the package with the following command and check in the  package.json:
npm install angular2-cookie --save

Comment: How is it going with this case? Did below answer fix above issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be caused by the angular2-cookie package not being installed in azure pipeline.

1,You can go to the package.json file to check if the angular2-cookie package is added to the dependencies or devDependencies. If not, you need to run `npm install angular2-cookie` locally. npm install command will automatically add  angular2-cookie to dependencies. Or you can manually add angular2-cookie to dependencies. Then push the changes to git repo.

2,Then you also need to check your pipeline task. You need npm task or a script task to install the dependencies. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code#using-a-script-to-install-with-packagejson) for examples.

```
- script: npm install

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
  command: 'install'
```

Please check if you add some flags(ie.`--production, --only ...`) to the `npm install` command in your pipeline (eg. `npm install --only=dev`). If you use one of these flags in npm istall command. It will will cause some packages not being installed.

it is recommanded to use `npm install`, for it will install all the packages listed in dependencies and devDependencies.